# My vb.NET project input doesn't in my primepairs function . how can I fix them?

Tags: vb.net

```vb
Sub PrimePair()
        Dim n As Integer
        Dim count As Integer = 0
        Console.WriteLine(count)
    End Sub
    Public Function PrimePairs(ByVal n As Integer, ByVal n2 As Long) As Integer
        Dim count As Integer = 0
        Console.ReadLine()
        If n Mod 2 = 0 Then
            For i = 1 To (n / 2) + 1
                n2 = CLng(n - i)
                If IsPrime(CLng(i)) And IsPrime(n2) = True Then
                    count += 1
                End If
            Next
        Else
            n2 = n - 2
            If IsPrime(n2) = True Then
                count = +1
            End If
        End If
        Console.WriteLine(count)
        Return n
    End Function
End Module>
```

I can't run my code without sub. I created two functions, but the inputs I entered do not return in functions and do not print on the screen, I hope I can solve it, thanks for your attention. My project calculates how many different ways it prints the entered input value as a sum of prime numbers. About the Goldbach conjecture

Comment: If this is vb.net, why do you tag it with *visual-c++* and *vba*. And are you using VSCode or Visual Studio? And what kind of Application is this, a console app?

Comment: In case there is a logic error in your program, please explain the method you are using so that we can check if the program you've written is doing what you intend.

Comment: my  progra produce just that statistic: how many different pairs of
primes sum to a given number.for example fourteen is the first even number with two different pairs, (3,11) and
(7,7). Eighteen has three pairs, (1,17), (5,13), and (7,11).

Comment: @özgün I suggest that you generate a list of prime numbers first. Then you can iterate over those instead of iterating over numbers which you have to check for primality every time even though they've been checked before. Then you subtract a known prime from the number being investigated and check if the result is in the list of primes. (As long as you create the primes in ascending order, you can use the [List<T>.BinarySearch Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.binarysearch) for a fast check.)